# Jquery on("click") doesn't work on previous chrome android browsers

Tags: jquery

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click",".addQuestIcon",function () {
  question+=1;
  var switchCh='ch'+question;
  $('#questionsNumber').text(question);
  var formId=$(".thisForm").attr('id');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'insert.php',
    dataType:  false,
    type: 'post',
    data: 'formid' + '=' + formId +'&' + 'addQuestion' + '=' + question ,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
      var questID='q'+$.trim(data);
      $("input[name=" +"q"+ question + "]").attr('id',questID);
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
      alert(errorThrown.message)
    }
  });
  ...//continue
```

This code works properly on desktop browsers and updated Android Chrome, but not on later versions.

Comment: I assume, that you forgot to wrap the code in `$(document).ready(function() { /* your_code */ });`.

Comment: Was that it? @Hamid hp ?

Comment: Sounds like a matter of using the right version of jQuery.

Comment: No. it's wraped in document ready

Comment: i'm using jquery 2.1.3